# How does 儘 + 管 compound to mean "despite”?

Tags: etymology

despite's ["prepositional sense "notwithstanding" (early 15c.) is short for in despite of "in defiance or contempt of" (c. 1300), a loan-translation of Anglo-French *en despit de* "in contempt of.""](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=despite).

[Cambridge English-Chinese Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-traditional/despite) synonymizes "despite", before translating it". I understand how 管 means "influence".

> without taking any notice of or being influenced by; not prevented by
> 不管；儘管；無論

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-chinese/despite) skips the intermediate step. p 317, [*ABC Chinese–English Comprehensive Dictionary* (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Chinese%E2%80%93English_Dictionary).  I can't access the ["slightly revised through July 2005" ed.](https://wenlin.com/abc%22)

[image]

p 451, *op. cit.*

[image]

But what  does 儘 signify here? What semantic notions underlie 儘 and "despite"?

Answer (score 1):

One of the meanings of `儘` is `no matter` (任凭,纵使),

> 《左传·文十四年》：公子商人，**尽**其家贷於公。
> 《礼·曲礼》：虚坐尽后，食坐**尽**前。俗作尽。

So `儘 + 管` could be translated (literally) to `no matter what the influence is`

---

> I'm just a native speaker, not a profession. I don't have an answer here, but I may share some of my thoughts that might be helpful.

In the second image, do notice it is `盡` not `儘` (however both characters simplify to `尽`, making `尽` has 2 pronunciations(`jǐn` and `jìn`)

And in `儘管` it (only) pronounces `jǐn`

It shall be notice that compounding Chinese characters to words doesn't simplify compound their meanings.

Traditionally, I mean in Classical Chinese, `儘` already means `despite`. However the meaning of it twisted slightly (in most cases it means `to the greatest extent`  and `always`)

The same thing goes with `雖然` and `但是`. If you split the characters and find out each of their meanings, you would find that `雖` and `但` literally mean the same.